# How to make single digit integer into two digits

Tags: java, time, format, printf

I am trying to write a program in Java that compares to times and displays them in order. Everything works, except for the fact that if someone entered for example a 10 for the hour, and a 9 for the minute, it prints as "10:9".

I would like for each single digit to have a 0 in front of it when it prints. The h variable stands for hour and the m variable stands for minute

```
System.out.printf("First time: %02d" , h1 , ":%02d" , m1 , "\nSecond time: %02d" , h2 , ":%02d" , m2);
```

Comment: If those are times of day, use the `LocalTime` class from java.time (the modern Java date and time API). Its `toString` method produces a string like `10:09` (granted that its seconds are 0, which I presume they will be in your case). If your times are amounts of time or durations, use the `Duration` class, but keep your own formatting logic.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt that that code is printing "10:9". It will instead likely only print `First time: 10`.

Your formatting strings look good, but the way that you're calling `System.out.printf` isn't quite right. `java.io.PrintStream.printf` has the following signature:

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args)
```

It expects one formatting string and then any number of `Object`s as arguments to be used to transform that formatting string. `args` is used in-order whenever an identifier is found like `%d`. So instead of intermixing your formatting strings and your arguments, you would want to instead write one long formatting string, and then list your arguments in the order they appear in `format`.

```
System.out.printf("First time: %02d:%02d\nSecond time: %02d%02d", h1, m1, h2, m2);
```